# removeListener в Chrome extension not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Here is the contents of background.js:

```
var toggle = false;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  toggle = !toggle;
  if(toggle) {
    var start_working = function() {
                            chrome.tabs.query({ url: ["http://*/*","https://*/*"], currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
                                 for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {   
                                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, {code : "var enabled = 1;"});
                                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, {file: 'js/new.js'});
                                    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "add48.png", tabId:tabs[i].id});
                                 }
                            });
                        }
    if (!chrome.tabs.onUpdated.hasListener(start_working)) {
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(start_working);
        chrome.tabs.query({url: ["http://*/*","https://*/*"]}, function (tabs) {
                console.log('1start_working='+chrome.tabs.onUpdated.hasListener(start_working));
                console.log('1toggle='+toggle);
                for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, {code : "var enabled = 1;"});
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, {file: 'js/new.js'});
                    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "add48.png", tabId:tabs[i].id});
                }
            }
        );
    }
  } else {
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(start_working);
    console.log('2start_working='+chrome.tabs.onUpdated.hasListener(start_working));
    console.log('2toggle='+toggle);
    chrome.tabs.query({url: ["http://*/*","https://*/*"], currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
            for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, {code : "var enabled = 0; $('#sort_g').remove();"});
                chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "add48_off.png", tabId:tabs[i].id});
            }
        }
    );
    return false;
  }
});
```

Here is the code of manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Ds",
  "version": "0.2",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "icons": { 
    "48": "add48.png",
    "128": "add128.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "add48_off.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "notifications",
        "*://*/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "all_frames": true
      }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["tpl/panel.html"]
}
```

When we click on the application icon, we add an element to all the HTML tabs and make the icon "active", and when we click the icon again, we change the icon to gray and remove the html element from all pages.

Also, when updating the html tab, the element should again appear and the extension icon should be active.

All this is implemented, but after disabling the extension, an html element still appears, although the new.js script should not be connected and `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.hasListener(start_working)=false`

Here's the log after disabling the extension:

`background.js:49 2start_working=false
background.js:50 2toggle=false`

But when updating the tab anyway, the html element appears on the page

I can not understand why this happens? Moreover, the console shows that after disabling the extension, when updating the page, the new.js script is connected already 3 times.

Comment: You're creating a brand new `start_working` function every time so removing it does nothing because it was never registered. You need to move the function into global scope.

Comment: @wOxxOm The problem is solved. Thank you so much! Only it is still not clear why after updating the tab the script new.js is executed 3 times